# Site integrated with discord

Tags: discord, discord.js, fetch

I was just wondering, how can I post to a website (in this case a dashboard) with information from a discord server? For example, the number of members, number of admins, all the people with information like name, the chat history and so on? I’m new to this genre of things (only discord to site integration, Js is fine for me :) )

Btw I will post a GitHub page if everything works so you can have the source code and tweaking it for your server!

Thank you in advance and I hope someone will explain me how to do that and what I have to use!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display this on the frontend which is connected using a backend I would use fetch/axios to call the Guild API EndPoint https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild
The Function can be

```
    return axios.get<PartialGuild>(`https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/${serverId}?with_counts=true`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
```

If you don't use typescript you can remove the `<PartialGuild>` as its used to typecast. The Partial Guild is helpful as you can set the object to items you only need and return that back to the front-end.

Make Aprox memberCount & Presence count optional as they are only returned if with_counts=true

```
export type PartialGuild = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  owner: boolean;
  permissions: string;
  features: string[];
 approximate_member_count?: number;
 approximate_presence_count?: number;
};
```

If you don't have a backend where you can fetch this and only have a front-end + Discord Bot you could setup a websocket where the dashboard communicates directly with the front-end (this wouldn't be a recommended idea and a back-end would be more suitable for this). However I assume you have a backend because the front-end should only display this information to people who have been authorized.

You can repeat the process for other information from different EndPoints (check out the rest of the docs)
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members
this will fetch guild members for a specified guild and with this you can filter the users by roles.

Comment: thank you mate, I will dig into it!